# Actionscript 3.0 import external linkage from swf works only once

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

When I load externall SWF and load class from it the externall classes are loaded only once
I use the following code to load externall class that I found on the website.
The problem is that applicationDomain works only once, which means after the swf file loaded once its not loading again. In other words i load externall class (linkage) which contains movieclip only for once and later it doesnt work. I think the problem is because i use applicationDomain. any way to solve the problem?

```
    var sym:MovieClip;
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        var req=URLRequest = new URLRequest("foo.swf");
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fooLoadComplete);
        loader.load(req):

        function fooLoadComplete (event:Event):void
        {
        var classDefinition:Class=event.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("Symbol1") as Class;
        sym=new ClassDefinition();
        addChildren();
        }
    function addChildren():void{
    addChild(sym);
    }
```

Comment: Possibly related to "SWF Reloading" [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/)?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by : "works only once" but I think that your external classes should be declared **global** to be accessible more than once ...